# SpeechRecognitionEngine Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm running some simple main method code that instantiates a SpeechRecognitionEngine and passes some grammar data to it. I can't seem to find why the error keeps coming up. I tried deleting the .csproj and .suo and nothing changed.

```
        SpeechRecognitionEngine spe = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        Choices commands = new Choices();
        commands.Add("hello", "what is your name");
        GrammarBuilder gB = new GrammarBuilder(commands);
        Grammar g = new Grammar(gB);

        //every single call to spe.SomeMethod() breaks with the error in the title
        spe.LoadGrammarAsync(g);
        spe.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        spe.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, figured it out:
Go to: 
Build>Configuration Manager>Active Solution Platform
Click the 'Any CPU' dropdown.
Select 
Set the platform to the compatible Speech SDK type (in my case x64)
enjoy your robotic servant program in the making

ps. save yourself the headache and use RecognizeAsync() and not Recognize(). Recognize likes to proc twice for some reason.